# If f(x) < g(x) for all x, does it necessarily follow that lim f(x) < lim g(x) as x approaches a?

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality

I am aware that the answer is no.

However, I attempted to come up with a proof.
Let lim f(x) = L and lim g(x) = M, and assume that L >= M. Adding f(x) < g(x) and M <= L gives f(x) + M < g(x) + L, ie. f(x) - L < g(x) - M.
If g(x) - M > 0, then there exists ε > 0 for which f(x) - L < ε < g(x) - M is true. For that ε, there also exists δ = min (δ', δ") > 0 (where δ' and δ" values are from the definitions of lim f(x) and lim g(x) for that ε) for which 0 < |x-a| < δ implies |f(x) - L| < ε and |g(x) - M| < ε. Consequently, for an x such that 0 < |x-a| < δ, g(x) - M < ε is true -- a contradiction.
If g(x) - M <= 0, then there exists ε > 0 for which f(x) - L < g(x) - M < -ε holds. For that ε, there exists a δ as defined above and an x such that 0 < |x-a| < δ, implying that g(x) - M > -ε -- a contradiction. As a result, L < M. 
What is wrong with this "proof"?

Comment: Actually, the answer is no.  $f(x)=x^2$, $g(x)=2x^2, x\neq 0;g(0)=1$, choose $a=0$

Comment: @tom - I don't see your point.

Comment: if there is a limit at point $a$, then the limits as x--> a for f, g are: f(a) and g(a) exist and f(a)<g(a) by definition.

Comment: @NoChance In my example, $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x$ but $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$.

Comment: @NoChance $f$ and $g$ may not be continuous.

Comment: @Tom, I see thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE; this is a great question, and showing your work is particularly nice. We use "MathJax" to format math here; you can learn 90% of what you need by reading just a few lines of this tutorial, and then keep referring back as you ask or answer new questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . Sadly, the answers you've gotten here in the comments aren't very high-quality --- they fail to answer the very particular question you asked, which was "where's the error in the proof," not "why is the claim false". That happens.

Comment: ...unfortunately, you get what you pay for. The good news is that someone with better reading/answering skills is likely to also give a good answer in a little while, and possibly someone else will reformat your math to make it more readable to everyone, and you'll be on your way. Again, welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the "proof" is in the step where you go from saying that $f(x)-L < g(x)-M$ to saying that there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(x) - L < \epsilon < g(x) - M$.  The issue stems from needing to be a bit more careful with quantifiers.  In that step the $\epsilon$ you obtain depends on $x$ - you could be getting a different $\epsilon$ for each choice of $x$.  However, your argument then goes on to treat $\epsilon$ as a constant, and chooses which $x$ to consider based on $\epsilon$.  That introduces a circularity, which breaks the proof.